# Reopen: Should I talk to my team lead about unintentional sexism within the team?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-request

[Should I talk to my team lead about unintentional sexism within the team?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/70670/should-i-talk-to-my-team-lead-about-unintentional-sexism-within-the-team)

This question is just "How to deal with unintentional sexism within my team?" with one possible solution fronted.

It is no more opinion based than [How to deal with a difficult team consisting mostly of senior members?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27899/how-to-deal-with-a-difficult-team-consisting-mostly-of-senior-members?rq=1), [How to help a junior developer that refuses help?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42357/how-to-help-a-junior-developer-that-refuses-help?rq=1), [How to deal with meddling coworkers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/how-to-deal-with-meddling-coworkers), [How to interview a former superior?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44113/how-to-interview-a-former-superior), etc.

Actually, much *more* research has been done about sexism in the workplace.

The OP does include the word "should," but that's the missing verb in the favored "how to" questions. Hiding it doesn't make them less opinion based.

This is a common workplace issue and other people are likely to have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

The question was reopened by the community.  Thank you for raising the issue here on meta.